Cannot fetch in JavaScript because of CORS error
I'm a student, this is just for a big assignment where I have to get a name from Gravatar, so I do not need to worry about anything from security and such. When I try to fetch it gives me this error:

Access to fetch at 'https://www.gravatar.com/0edeae5191311f8c54a0cd89aba9d480.json' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Here is the code:
async function GetUserData(){
    const url = `https://www.gravatar.com/${hash}.json`;
    const resp = await fetch(url);
    const data = await resp.json;
    console.log(data);
}

Is there a normal simple way to solve this?
I tried adding { mode: 'no-cors'}, it did not work.

From a page served to a browser, you cannot access domains different from your own source domain unless the target domain explicitly allows it. That's what CORS means. This is an extremely common question here.
